# uv mesh propertional editing behaves strange

Tags: uv, transforms, uv-image-editor, proportional-editing

When I move a uv mesh vertex with proportional editing enabled, it doesn't behave as expected. The vertices that moves with the selected vertex are not the surrounding vertices but further away.
See the animated gif movie below. Is this behavior as expected, a bug or just me using the tool wrong?
I'm using Blender 2.90.1

[image]

Comment: Hello :). This looks like a bug in 2.9 when *UV Sync Selection* is enabled. No similar issues in 2.83 though. You can use [This helpful guide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173685/78972) to see whether it's a Bug that should be reported.